# Using sockets with scalajs

Tags: scala, sockets, scala.js

I'm trying to use sockets in my scalaJs code ,I have a real time game and wanted to send messages between tow players does web sockets work with scalaJs?

Comment: As a brief and superficial google search immediately shows [(1)](https://bitbucket.org/prassee/scala-js-websocket/src/9ebf9e012670463d6a7f8918a24231d4782827c7/src/main/scala/chat/ChatExample.scala?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#ChatExample.scala-21) [(2)](https://github.com/jrudolph/akka-http-scala-js-websocket-chat/blob/master/frontend/src/main/scala/example/akkawschat/Frontend.scala#L34), the answer is "Yes". Do you have any *specific* questions that might be considered on-topic? In this case, please show what you tried exactly, preferably with an [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is "Yes".

The more useful answer is that just about anything you can do with JavaScript, you can do with Scala.js, so likely all JS websocket libraries can be used with SJS. If you don't find a Scala.js-specific library that suits your needs, you should look for a JavaScript one, and then write [a Scala.js facade](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/facade-types.html) (which is generally pretty straightforward) to hook it up to SJS.